# iTunes Connect problem

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

When I try to do the following: Login Itunes connect -> Manage your applications -> Choose an app -> Rights and Pricing, then it returns an error, saying:

> Cannot Process Request
>
> An error has occurred processing your request. Please try again later or send an e-mail for assistance.

This only happens with my mac safari browser, but not on chrome, and not even on iPhone safari. Anyone got an idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a bug on their website. This is only something that you, the app developer, need to use and not your app users? So can't you report it to apple and work around the problem with Chrome until Apple fix it? (Like it says: "send an e-mail for assistance".) Failing that you can try looking at the source of the request that's failing - in Chrome dev tools or Firebug if it's AJAX - to see if there's anything there, but chances are the error's only in Apple's log files on their server.

Answer (score 13):

(I'm late to the party, but in case anyone else stumbles across this Q.)

Try deleting cookies for the site. This worked for me (in the opposite direction — Chrome was broken).

Comment: Deleting cookies did not work, but "Remove all website data" did. (Safari -> Reset Safari...)

Comment: it did not working for me, i use Safari and also try it in firefox, can somebody give me a clue?

Comment: Did not work for me. It's been three years now. Come on Apple!

Answer (score 1):

the same thing happened to me this week as well, I am using the Firefox browser so while waiting for a reply from Apple I cleared the history and cache etc. From there I was once again able to log in to my iTunes Connect account as usual.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just logged out and logged in again and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with other internet connection, worked for  me. May be the problem is accruing due to some proxies or blocking on your internet connection. Also try with other browser or system may resolve your problem.